# How to remove a positional parameter from $@

Tags: shell, shell-script, arguments

Basically, I want to "pluck out" the first occurrence of `-inf` from the parameter list.  (The remaining parameters will be passed along to a different command.)

The script I have has the following structure:

```
#!/bin/sh

<CODE>

for POSITIONAL_PARAM in "$@"
do

    <CODE>

    if [ "$POSITIONAL_PARAM" = '-inf' ]
    then
        <PLUCK $POSITIONAL_PARAM FROM $@>
        break
    fi

    <CODE>

done

<CODE>

some-other-command "$@"

# end of script
```

Is there a good way to do this?

BTW, even though I am mainly interested in answers applicable to `/bin/sh`, I am also interested in answers applicable only to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @cuonglm: I've reverted to the original form of the pseudo code; in my experience, whenever I simplify the picture too much, I get answers that work for the oversimplified case, but not for the actual one.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

POSIXly:

```
for arg do
  shift
  [ "$arg" = "-inf" ] && continue
  set -- "$@" "$arg"
done

printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

The above code even works in pre-POSIX shells, except the original Almquist shell (Read [Endnote](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/bourne_args/)). Change the `for` loop to:

```
for arg
do
  ...
done
```

guarantee to work in all shells.

---

Another POSIX one:

```
for arg do
  shift
  case $arg in
    (-inf) : ;;
       (*) set -- "$@" "$arg" ;;
  esac
done
```

With this one, you need to remove the first `(` in `(pattern)` to make it work in pre-POSIX shells.

Comment: Thanks.  That argument cycling technique is very nice.  It has the added bonus that it makes it very easy to inspect the parameter following the current one (since it's just sitting right there in `$1`).  This property came in handy in what I'm doing.  Also, thanks for reminding me that the `in "$@"; ` bit at the top of the `for` loop is unnecessary.  It's something I've seen before, but I tend to forget it.  Regarding your remark on the Almquist shell, does the `do` *have* to appear on the next line, or would `for arg; do` work too?

Comment: `for arg; do` work in Almquist shell

Comment: For the unininitiated `for arg do` is a shorthand idiom for `for arg in "$@"; do`. That threw me for about 5 seconds! Some might say the latter is more readable :)

Comment: I was not getting how the `for ... case` example was working until I added an `echo "$@"` after the `esac` line and "voila!" Very clever, just selectively copying the keepers onto the end of the $@ array through the entire list. My mental chalkboard was failing me... Thanks for this nice, clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question whilst trying to solve a similar problem, however I wanted to process all non-option arguments (those not beginning with `-`) up to any received `--` separator. I wanted to pluck out the processed arguments only and leave the remaining ones in situ in the order supplied.

Here is what I came up with.

```
parse=true
for arg do
  [ "$arg" == '--' ] && parse=false
  shift
  if $parse && [ "${arg:0:1}" != '-' ]
  then
    echo handling $arg
  else
    set -- "$@" "$arg"
  fi
done
```