# Is there a standard array name for $@, like ${ARGS[@]}?

Tags: bash, bash-expansion

I don't expect it to be modifiable. That is, I don't expect it to enable something like `ARGS=("${ARGS[@]}")`, but only to simplify something like `myarray=("${ARGS[@]/--unneeded-argument/}")`.

Note that the `--unneeded-argument` example is not meant to imply removing arguments is **the** reason why I'm asking. It's a question I've had in mind for years and I never got a definitive answer.

Comment: You want to delete a few args from `$@`?

Comment: What do you mean with "a standard name"? Is there some particular reason to not just use `$@` or `@`? What do you actually want to achieve in the end?

Comment: @ilkkachu I mean "standard array" as in "regular array". Regular arrays in Bash have names rather than special symbols; they support "${NAME[@]}" expansion.

Comment: @Inian Yes, this is what I want for now.

Comment: @Inian It's not a duplicate. That's why I said "for now". I was also curious specifically about this syntax thing. I've wondered this since quite a few years ago.

Comment: @argle, the thing here is that the special parameters with symbols for names are an ancient thing, and the named arrays only came later (in ksh? or whatever). Then I suppose `@` and `*` were allowed as indexes since they were already used in the array-like special parameters. If the shell was created now, it hopefully wouldn't have `$@`... (Even Perl has `@ARGV` to contain the arguments, instead of an array with a symbol for a name.)

Comment: A question should have a specific scope so that it's answerable. (In re: argle's comment "this is what I want for now") -- VTC as duplicate.

Comment: It certainly reads that way, particularly with your example of removing an "--unneeded-argument". Perhaps you could spell it out a bit more in your question?

Comment: (I'll be happy to reopen the question if it appears to be different from the duplicate while allowing the existing answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s no “regular array” corresponding to `$@`.

However you *can* use `@` in many scenarios involving arrays (but not as `${@[@]}` as you asked in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502042/is-there-a-standard-array-name-for-like-args/502045?noredirect=1#comment925421_502042) — `$@` is already a `@` expansion):

```
$ set 1 2 3
$ array=("$@")
$ echo "${array[0]}"
1
$ echo "${array[1]}"
2
$ myarray=("${@/2/}")
$ echo "${myarray[@]}"
1 3
```

In the last step however, the result might not be quite what you’re after — the array still has three elements, one of which is empty, since the replacement is applied to all the array elements individually.

Comment: As I explained in a comment, by "standard" I mean "regular". So I guess the best approach is answering no (which I suspect is indeed the case but an explicit stackexchange confirmation is good for us all), to which your example above acts as a workaround. Otherwise the answer is useful and ready to be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

`"$@"` does the same to the positional parameters that `"${foo[@]}"` does to an array variable `foo`. Like Stephen said, you can use `@` in expansions that take braces, e.g. the slice notation `"${@:1:2}"` would be the same as `"$1" "$2"`. (Leaving the second number out expands to the rest of list, e.g. `"${@:2}"` expands to `"$2"` and all positional parameters after that.)

This is in line with named variables, here, the "name" of the special parameter is `@`, and the `$` at the front just triggers the expansion. Note that the braces are optional for a plain expansion (without indexing or string manipulation inside). So `"${@}"` is the same as `"$@"`, and you could even write `"${@:1}"` to the same effect, since the indexing on `@` starts at one, not zero.

But you *can't* use `${@[@]}`, or `${@[1]}`. They're just `$@` and `$1`, respectively. (In a sense, `$@` is already like `${args[@]}`, so you can't index it further.) This also means that if you want to index into the positional parameters, you'll need to use the slice expansion, e.g. `${@:i:1}` to get the element at position *i*.

---

However, do note that the string-manipulation expansions on arrays or `@` apply to all elements individually. E.g. here, `oo` is removed from `foo` and from `oo`, but there's still the third element of `@` left, it's just empty:

```
$ set -- foo bar oo
$ printf ":%s:\n" "${@/oo}"
:f:
:bar:
::
```

If you want to actually remove the element, you'll have to do something else, like loop over the values and drop the one you don't want. This is probably easier with the help of a named array rather than by trying to do it just within `$@`. Say, something like this:

```
a=();
for x in "$@"; do
    if [[ $x != oo ]]; then
        a+=("$x");
    fi;
done
```

Or any of the (much better) answers to this questions: [How to remove a positional parameter from $@](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258512/170373)

Comment: It's great to know about `"${@:1:2}"`. Is there a way to reference all arguments? Something like `"${@:*}"`?

Comment: @argle, well, _all_ arguments is just `"$@"` :) Though leaving the last number out would give the whole list starting a particular index, e.g. `"${@:3}"` would go from `"$3"` to the end. So, `"${@:1}"` would be the same as just `"$@"`, though more confusing.

Comment: (Note that `"$0"` is different from the other numbered parameters, it's not included in `"$@"`, but you can include it with `"${@:0}"`. Usually you wouldn't want to, it contains the name of the script.

Comment: +1 for the great examples in comments. It would be very useful if you added at least the `"${@:1}"` to the answer as the only true "$@" expansion equivalent available.

Comment: @argle, edited, but note that `"${@}"` is also the same as `"$@"` in the same way `"${foo}"` is the same as `"$foo"`. (It gets more amusing with `$$`, it can be written as `${$}` which looks really weird.)

Comment: @argle, Sure, `$foo` is the same as `${foo}`, but not the same as `${foo[@]}`. The braces are just needed to use an index, but they can be used without one, and you need them in `${foo}bar`, since `$foobar` is a different variable.  If `foo` is an array, then expanding it without an index refers to element `0`, so `$foo` is actually the same as `${foo[0]}`. (In ksh-style arrays like in Bash, that is. Zsh is different) That's some kind of a backwards-compatibility thing too.

Comment: (move to chat if you like, though I have to do something else now)